# Exception in paypal integration with salesforce

Tags: integration, paypal

I have done paypal integration using soap request. Previously it was working fine and now am getting error like below..

```
"System.XmlException: ParseError at [row,col]:[7,3] Message: The element type "p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "/p".
```

From paypal am getting raw response like:

```
 <HTML><HEAD>
   <TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
   The requested URL "&#47;2&#46;0&#47;", is invalid.<p>
   </BODY></HTML>
```

This means...

Invalid URL
   The requested URL "/2.0/", is invalid.

i have provided end point URL as  " https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/ " as a string.

Comment: Hi did u get the answer, i am also searching for the same answer..

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Can you tell me whether you got any fix for this issue? Thanks.